# Google Image search base url for non ajax usage

Tags: google-api

I would like to use Google Image search, however I can't find the proper url anywhere. Examples [always refer](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Search) to the web search, not the image search. I do not want to use javascript, I need the iamge at server side.

Please, do not simply post links to the API documentation, but preferably the url itself. (Or the missing url argument etc).

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web

This is a web search - no changing web to image/img doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right url is

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images